# Duplicate class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout found in modules design-25.3.1-runtime

Tags: android

Duplicate class `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` found in modules design-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:design:25.3.1) and `support-core-ui-27.1.1-runtime` (com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1)

I encountered this error and decided to post it as a question with a solution for anyone who might run into this.

Answer (score 0):

## Approaches

There are some approaches to fix this

1. Adding Support Libraries
2. Re-Installing SDK build-tools

## Adding Support Libraries

In order to use a Support Library, you must modify your application's project's classpath dependencies within your development environment. You must perform this procedure for each Support Library you want to use.

**To add a Support Library to your application project:**

Include Google's Maven repository in your project's build.gradle file.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()

        // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must
        // instead use:
        //
        // maven {
        //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
    //}
}
```

}

For each module in which you want to use a Support Library, add the library in the dependencies block of the module's build.gradle file. For example, to add the v4 core-utils library, add the following to your dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
}
```

**To Re-install build-tools**

Go to the SDK manager, click the "SDK Tools" tab. If the check-mark for "Support Repository" is selected, unselect it and click OK. This will delete all of the files in the repository. Then recheck the check-mark, click GO and reinstall the repository.

## Links

1. [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html)
2. [Add build dependencies](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#groovy)